# Crystal Reports - How to dynamically change an image size

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a custom image in Crystal Reports (I send the URL as text and use it within the image properties), which displays fine. The thing is, the image can be one of two sizes. The good thing is, I know via the parameters I send to Crystal Reports which type of image is going to be displayed.

So, I send both `URL: "www.x.com", Type: "A"`, for example, as parameters. My only issue is, how do I change the size of the image now that, within Cystal Reports, I know its type, and therefore, which size it should have?

I guess I could make two different reports, identical, except for the size of that particular image, but is there a way to dynamically change its size within Crystal Reports itself?

Comment: I think you could add the picture twice and decide wether to show vie Suppress-Formula depending on Type

Comment: I did try that (Showed both images, with their appropiate sizes, and in the URL do something like "if is type A, show the URL, if not, then empty URL", but, even though it doesn't show the image, it does keep its place, so the "invisible" image is making the page larger.

Comment: So you didn't use the suppress-formula. Try to put both pictures on the same spot and suppress vie formula

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use two sections (split the current section). Show/Hide only one of them.

Option 2: at least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports User Function Libraries (UFLs) listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provides a function to on-the-fly resize an image.

So in the graphic location property you would use the UFL to a) download the image to the local hard drive, b) resize it, and c) get the resized image.

The advantage of the UFL approach is that it also provides other useful options such as image cropping.